# Angular JS Rest Service Protecting access key

Tags: python, django, angularjs, base64

I want to talk to my rest service directly through Angular js . How do i protect my HTTP AccessKeys and Multitenant Ids .. SO that it wont be visible to others . I am using Python Django as my service side Language .. How do i encrypt keys ? IS there Any Encryption methods ?

Comment: encryption won't help you much without https

Comment: Then how can i acheive this ??